What is the difference between match and print in Karate
How match vs print works what is the difference?
Feature: Create and verify User

  Background:
      * def createRandomUser =
      """
      function() {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
        const email = 'user' + random + '@example.com';
        const name = 'Name' + random;
        const surname = 'Surname' + random;
        return { email: email, name: name, surname: surname };
      }
      """

  Scenario: Create random user and verify
    Given def randomUser = createRandomUser()
    When def newUser = call read('CreateNewUser.feature') { randomUser: '#(randomUser)' }
    And match newUser.response.email == randomUser.email
    And match newUser.response.name == randomUser.name
    And match newUser.response.surname == randomUser.surname
    Then def usersList = call read('GetAllUsers.feature')
    And match usersList.response[-1].email == randomUser.email
    And match usersList.response[-1].name == randomUser.name
    And match usersList.response[-1].surname == randomUser.surname

In this example i have user creating with adding him to the list , and when i try to print usersList.response[-1] i receive null but when I'm matching it with randomUser.email it shows true, so why printing shows null while matching shows that it has actual value ? I printed after then randomUser.email and it shows created email
I tried to print usersList.response[-1] while print usersList.response shows all values that was in response, also usersList.response[usersList.response.length - 1] shows correct mail not null

Short answer, print takes "normal" JS on the right but match handles JSON-path by default.
You can use JS if you enclose it in round brackets. For example:
* def foo = [1, 2]
* print foo[foo.length - 1]
* match (foo[foo.length - 1]) == 2

